# How do I access databound dataset for control programatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, webforms

I have a `DropDownList` control which is databound via a `SqlDataSource` whose query returns 3 fields (`Label`, `Value`, and `Active`) - Is there a way to access the databound dataset programatically to check whether the `Active` flag is true or false?

I know that this can be done DURING the databind, but I need the `Active` flag to checked during `PreRender` phase as the control may need to select a value where `Active=false` if loading an old record where this selection had been made. (During `PreRender`, I'm removing all `Active=false` items, unless it's the value that I'm setting the `DropDownList` to).

I have this working perfectly by populating a `DataView` with a `SqlDataSource`. Select and comparing/removing items based on this, but hitting the database twice to get this info a second time for each control seems inefficient.

Also, I can't write a piece of reusable/generic code for all controls as my current method only works when the `SqlDataSource` doesn't require any `SelectArguments`. If I can access the databound data directly, this would bypass this problem too.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: Programmatically setting a control's data source is much more flexible than using a SqlDataSource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main problem you're having comes from using a SqlDataSource as your data-access. SqlDataSources are easy to set up and give you instant results, but they are extremely inflexible and require reuse across pages.

I would create a function that grabs the data from the database and stores it in an List or IEnumerable. If the data is in a List then you have access to it programmatically and validation is much easier to achieve.

Here is a sample below that uses the Entity Framework to access the database

**Mark up**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTest" runat="server"></asp>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public List<Record> GetAllRecordsByUserName(string credentials)
{
    List<Record> recordList;
    using (CustomEntities context = new CustomEntities())
    {

        IQueryable<Record> recordQuery = from records in context.Records
                                              where records.UserName == credentials
                                              select records; 
        recordList = recordQuery.ToList<Record>();
    }
    return recordList;
}

public void ValidateAndBind(string username)
{
    List<Record> recordList = GetAllRecordsByUserName(username);

    // Do validation here

    ddlTest.DataSource = recordList;
    ddlTest.DataBind();
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ValidateAndBind("test.username");
}
```

You can use whatever data-access method you desire, but setting it programmatically allows you to reuse it across pages. In the methods above I created it in the page for terms of space. In practice, you should create a class that handles specific data retrieval, which is usually called a *Data Access Layer*.